# How to change headerStyle of Drawer Navigator based on Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

**I resolved this specific problem separating in different files the navigation components, with this way the component doesn't rerender anymore**

First of all: i'm using React Native. I have a TabNavigator nested into a DrawerNavigator

i'm trying to change the color of the drawer header based on a specific screen into the Material Top Tab Navigator.

I tried to do it with screenListeners of the  TabNavigator with a boolean state but when i made a setState the TabNavigator is rerendered and jump to the Home screen again.

PD: The App have a top header from the drawer and the bottom tab from the tabNavigator. I need that both of them change the color when X screen is focus.
To do this for the bottom tab i used route.name but i can't access to this property from the parent navigator.

```
....
screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor:
              route.name === '[targetScreen]' ? '#6600A1' : theme.PRIMARY_COLOR,
          },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various options to provide a state in both directions, Redux, Recoil, Context Provider. If you are not already using one of them I think the Context Provider is the easiest. Basically it is a container around your outer navigator and inside you can access and change the state.